# How to read SMS stored in SIM card in Android

Tags: android, sms

I was wondering if anyone knew anything about programmatically getting the SMS messages off of your phone's sim card on an android platform.

I would like to write a program that allows you to save either individual messages or entire threads to the SD card, but after looking around for a bit, I have discovered that google decided to take out that api from the current android SDK.

I saw in a few places that there are hidden APIs for this, but no one knew what they were or how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage the SMS saved on the SIM card with the URI `content://sms/icc`. It works also with the last version of Android.

For example this prints the contents of the cursor to `System.out`:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/icc"), null, null, null, null);
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
```

You need the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

You can find a complete example here:
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/ManageSimMessages.java

Comment: The URI is specific for ICC (integrated circuit card) messages. As you can see in the Android repository, the SMS application have the activity [`ManageSimMessages`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/ManageSimMessages.java) to display the SMS stored in the SIM Card, and uses that URI.