# Android raw PDU

Tags: android, smsmanager, pdu

As I think method in SmsManager:

```
copyMessageToIcc(byte[] smsc, byte[] pdu, int status)
```

store raw PDU in Icc.
How to send message stored in Icc?

The same question is for method:

```
createMessageListFromRawRecords(List<SmsRawData> records)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you're asking, but the SMS Provider can [retrieve those messages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33854615), which you could then send with `SmsManager`.

Comment: How send this PDU stored (Icc, List) msg by SmsManager? Thre's no methods

Comment: When you retrieve the messages with the SMS Provider, you won't get raw PDUs. You'll get a `Cursor` that will have a `body` column that holds the messages in plain text.

Comment: OK but my PDU is silent/ping type. Any text is not including. I want send PDU without any konversion.

Comment: That's something you should've mentioned in the question. How do you know that they're even being saved? AFAIK, those are usually acknowledged and then discarded.